# I need a (simple), immutable, 2D vector library for Java or Scala

Tags: java, scala, vector

I've been searching for a whole day. I've tried Simplex3D Scala library. But it's poorly documented and I don't even manage to get a vector normalized after downloading an older release because the current one doesn't run.

javax.vecmath is not immutable so it not nice to use in Scala.

commons-math is more into the scientific math direction with no convenience for 2D (or 3D) use.

Comment: The project http://code.google.com/p/sgine/ uses Simplex3D, maybe the examples or tests there could help you to figure out how things work. And one thing is sure: Simplex3D is *darn* fast.

Comment: @Landei I've even talked to one of the supposed devs of sgine on the IRC channel of Simplex3D.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find one when I needed one.  So I built one, and I've always been intending to release it.  I'm too busy to do anything with it now, but I could probably make it available next week if a better answer is not forthcoming.

Comment: Debugging.  Fiddling with matrices.  Trying to decide how large of a library is too large, and what sort of size/speed tradeoffs are okay and what routines should be in it.  Probably will throw it up somewhere accessible by the end of the week.

Comment: @ziggystar - Something else came up that I need to devote all my time to, so I've put up what I've got so far:  http://code.google.com/p/shipvl/downloads/list

Answer (score 2):

I've just done some more research. Slick2D seems to contain a Vector2f class that has immutable methods. Though that's not very much and can be done by hand in maybe an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the one I made for some simple game stuff.

It hardly perfect and it's not entirely immutable. I wanted non-immutable versions of the operators for some pieces of code. Originally it wrapped the Vector2 class of JBox2D as well, which lacked operator overloads and a bunch of other stuff.

```
package Ostkaka

import scala.math

/**
 * Date: 2010-okt-06
 */
class Vector2(private var _x: Float, private var _y: Float) {
  def x = _x
  def y = _y

  def +(v: Vector2) = {var c = Vector2(x, y); c += v; c}

  def +=(v: Vector2) = {
    this._x += v.x
    this._y += v.y
    ()
  }

  def -(v: Vector2) = {var c = Vector2(x, y); c -= v; v}

  def -=(v: Vector2) = {
    this._x -= v.x
    this._y -= v.y
    ()
  }

  def /(factor: Float) = {var c = Vector2(x, y); c /= factor; c}

  def /=(factor: Float) = {
    this *= (1 / factor);
    ()
  }

  def *(factor: Float) = {var c = Vector2(x, y); c *= factor; c}

  def *=(factor: Float) = {
    this._x *= factor
    this._y *= factor
    ()
  }

  def unary_- : Vector2 = Vector2(-x, -y)

  def magnitude = (math.sqrt (x * x + y * y).toDouble).toFloat

  def normalised = this / magnitude

  def dot(v: Vector2) = x * v.x + y * v.y

  def project(v: Vector2) = {
    val axis = v.normalised
    axis * (this dot axis)
  }
}

object Vector2
{

  def zero = new Vector2(0, 0)

  def unitX = new Vector2(1, 0)

  def unitY = new Vector2(0, 1)

  implicit def Tuple2FloatToVector2(v: (Float, Float)): Vector2 = {
    new Vector2(v._1, v._2)
  }

  def apply(): Vector2 = {
    new Vector2(0, 0)
  }

  def apply(x: Float, y: Float): Vector2 = {
    new Vector2(x, y)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thought I had functions for projection and the dot product as well but apparently not.

Comment: Added those in, written these functions so many times now I know them in my sleep. Every new language I learn I rewrite them lol.

Comment: You should use `.toDouble` and `.toFloat` instead of `.doubleValue` and `.floatValue`.  Check out the bytecode to see why!

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Interesting, I'll change those at once. How do you dump the bytecode listing easily? Long time since I disassembled anything JVM targeted.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Ahh, I see, ran javap -c on it and your `toDouble` and `toFloat` was made into opcodes. Using `doubleValue` and `floatValue` yielded `f2d` for the double but the rest compiled to nasty virtual functions into the standard library.

Comment: @Skurmedel: `javap -c MyClassName`.  To save you the trouble this time, `.floatValue` is a method on `java.lang.Double` and thus the answer has to be boxed from a primitive.  `.toFloat` is handled specially by the compiler (emits a single bytecode op `d2f`), and is equivalent to Java's `((float)myDoubleVar)`.

Comment: At least the -() method is wrong. That's exactly the reason why I'd like to use an established library. Spent 20 minutes to find that out. Omg, just checked, the += is wrong also. Probably nearly everything containing a bug.

Comment: @ziggystar: Yeah sorry about that, it's not the original version. The += is easy to fix though (just a minor typo), just did. But I don't see how the unary negation is wrong. And I understand you want to use an established library, but I never said this was the perfect vector class either.

Comment: @ziggystar: The version I have now posted works in my tests. But the negate was correct all along.

Comment: @Skurmedel. Sorry, don't remember the potential bug with -. I've dropped your file and written my own minimal class shortly after I posted. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplex3d Math follows GLSL very closely, so any manual on GLSL will work as well.

You can normalize vector 'v' as follows: normalize(v)

Simplex3d Math is a library and does not come with runnable classes, so I am not sure what you mean by "the new release does not run." Please join the mailing list and give more details, I'll be more than happy to assist you there: http://groups.google.com/group/simplex3d-dev

Documentation will be improved for the next release.

Comment: Well, of course I should have said that it did not compile. Actually, thinking in terms of C - it did not link. It couldn't find some classes byte code it seemed.

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? The project is compiled for Scala 2.8.1.final.

Comment: Well, it appears that the release script was not picking up recent source directories, hence the missing files. Fixed now.